# Edit/Remove "Tk" characters from tkinter window

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

Is it possible to edit/remove the "Tk" characters (inside green circle) from a tkinter window?

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to remove the icon, or the window title? And do you want to replace them with a custom icon or title, or just absolute blankness?

Comment: All of the above would be nice!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The red scripty Tk is the app icon.

On some platforms, you can replace that by using the [`iconbitmap`](http://wiki.tcl.tk/3177) or [`iconphoto`](http://wiki.tcl.tk/4528) functions. On others, you can't override the icon specified in the exe/bundle/etc. So, to do this cross-platform, you'll need to do it in your code, and also in your packaging (assuming you're planning to package and distribute binaries).

If you only care about Windows, `iconbitmap` with a Windows .ico file is the right solution. IIRC, on most *nix systems it's `iconbitmap` with a .xbm or `iconphoto` with a .xpm, while on Mac, it's… well, the app icon (which has to come from the bundle) isn't shown on the window at all, the *document* icon is shown there, and calling `iconbitmap` on a window sets the document icon to the Finder icon for the specified file.

See [this thread](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t339962-tkinter-iconbitmap-and-windows-xp.html) for an explanation of how to do it from Python.

As far as I know, Tk has no way to *remove* the app icon. Which is probably a good thing, because many platforms/window managers would end up showing some hideous "default app" in that place. But you can replace it with a 100%-transparent icon, which may be what you want.

---

The plain black tk is just window title. Give it any other window title, and the "tk" won't appear.

If you've already created a window and want to change its title, just call the `title` method:

```
my_frame.title('My new title, with no tk (except that one)')
```